# How to iterate array inside array data in laravel ,output are given below

Tags: php, laravel

**Out-put**

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:12 [▼
      "product_name" => "Raw Mango"
      "product_image" => "Raw_Mango_1997.jpg"
      "product_id" => "15"
      "variation_id" => "33"
      "original_price" => "15.31"
      "selling_price" => "12.25"
      "discount_price" => "3.06"
      "discount_percent" => "20"
      "product_stock" => "available"
      "product_unit" => "gram"
      "product_unit_value" => "250"
      "cart_quantity" => "1"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:12 [▼
      "product_name" => "Banana - Yelakki"
      "product_image" => "Banana_-_Yelakki_9339.jpg"
      "product_id" => "20"
      "variation_id" => "41"
      "original_price" => "56.25"
      "selling_price" => "45"
      "discount_price" => "11.25"
      "discount_percent" => "20"
      "product_stock" => "available"
      "product_unit" => "gram"
      "product_unit_value" => "500"
      "cart_quantity" => "1"
    ]
  ]
]
```

How to display this type of data in laravel blade page.I want to get data in object to show the data in laravel view page .I try many method but do not get solution please help me

**CartController.php**

```
public function viewCart(){

        $select=DB::table('carts')->where('user_id','=',Session::get('user_id'))->get();
        $count=count($select);
        if($count>0)
        {
            foreach($select as $row1)
            {
                $product_id     =   $row1->product_id;
                $variation_id   =   $row1->variation_id;
                $quantity       =   $row1->quantity;

                $sql=DB::table('products')->where('id','=',$product_id)->get();
                $arr=array();
                foreach($sql as $res)
                {
                    $product_name   =   $res->product_name;
                    $image          =   $res->product_image;
                    $product_desc   =   $res->product_desc;
                    $sql1=DB::table('product_details')->where('product_id','=',$product_id)->where('id','=',$variation_id)->get();
                    foreach($sql1 as $res1)
                    {
                        $original_price     =   $res1->original_price;
                        $selling_price      =   $res1->selling_price;
                        $discount_price     =   $res1->discount_price;
                        $discount_percent   =   $res1->discount_percent;
                        $product_stock      =   $res1->product_stock;
                        $product_unit       =   $res1->product_unit;
                        $product_unit_value =   $res1->product_unit_value;

                        $item_array=array(
                            'product_name'  =>$product_name,
                            'product_image' => $image,
                            'product_id'    =>  $product_id,
                            'variation_id' => $variation_id,
                            'original_price' => $original_price,
                            'selling_price' => $selling_price,
                            'discount_price' => $discount_price,
                            'discount_percent' => $discount_percent,
                            'product_stock' => $product_stock,
                            'product_unit' => $product_unit,
                            'product_unit_value' => $product_unit_value,
                            'cart_quantity' => $quantity
                        );
                        array_push($arr, $item_array);
                    }
                    $rows['product'][]=$arr;
                }
            }
            return View('cart-view',['products'=> $rows]);
        }
        else
        {
            return  view('cart-view');
        }


    }
```

I am trying to get user added cart details on page but when try foreach then its gives to error. how to iterete this type of data in laravel view page please help me .

Comment: You are doing it like a custom PHP CMS. In Laravel, you should be leveraging the eloquent's power. What you are looking can be achieved with a single line of code, i.e. `$cartItems = Cart::where('user_id', session()->get('user_id'))->with(['products']);` if models are created in a standard way with proper relationship definitions. And instead using a separate **product_details** table, you should be using the main **products** table and use a table to store meta info if needed. In short, you should be doing this the laravel way if you are using this framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the code as it is now, these are the queries being executed (shown to me by the [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)):

```
select * from `carts` where `user_id` = 1
select * from `products` where `id` = 15
select * from `product_details` where `product_id` = 15 and `id` = 33
select * from `products` where `id` = 20
select * from `product_details` where `product_id` = 20 and `id` = 41
```

It looks like a separate query is being executed for every single `product` and `product_details` record; not very efficient. Let's try this:

```
$carts = Cart::where('user_id', Session::get('user_id'))
    ->with('product.details')
    ->get();
```

For the above statement the following [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships) relationships are needed:

```
// Cart model
public function product() { 
return $this->belongsTo('App\Product'); 
}

// Product model
public function details() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\ProductDetails', 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

This looks a lot better; no matter how many product or product detail records are retrieved, no more than 3 queries are executed.

```
select * from `carts` where `user_id` = 1
select * from `products` where `products`.`id` in (15, 20)
select * from `product_details` where `product_details`.`product_id` in (15, 20)
```

Now to combine the model attributes with those of its relations:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($carts as $key => $cart) {
    $data[$key] = [
        'product_name' => $cart->product->product_name,
        'product_image' => $cart->product->product_image,
        'product_id' => $cart->product_id,
        'variation_id' => $cart->variation_id,
        'original_price' => $cart->product->details->original_price,
        'selling_price' => $cart->product->details->selling_price,
        'discount_price' => $cart->product->details->discount_price,
        'discount_percent' => $cart->product->details->discount_percent,
        'product_stock' => $cart->product->details->product_stock,
        'product_unit' => $cart->product->details->product_unit,
        'product_unit_value' => $cart->product->details->product_unit_value,
        'cart_quantity' => $cart->quantity,
    ];
}
```

Comment: how to get sub_total of cart ..@Joris1

Comment: You already have all the data in the Collection `$carts`, so you can probably achieve it using a Collection method, like `sum()`. See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#available-methods).

Comment: 'selling_price' => $cart->product->details->selling_price, geting wrong , i wants to get selling price according to variation_id

Comment: 'original_price' => $cart->product->details->original_price,
        'selling_price' => $cart->product->details->selling_price,
        'discount_price' => $cart->product->details->discount_price,
        'discount_percent' => $cart->product->details->discount_percent,
        'product_stock' => $cart->product->details->product_stock,
        'product_unit' => $cart->product->details->product_unit,

Comment: all worng data gives @JorisJ1

Comment: Please post a new question for this.

Comment: Hey @Dinesh, I notice you un-accepted my answer. Did I not answer your original question properly? It provides the output you state in the top of your question. I would be glad to expand on my answer if you modify your question, or even better make a new one.